# Is there a way to update and save the json files in the folder without opening it

Tags: python, json

In python, is there a way to update and save json files in the folder without opening it ?
For example,

There are 2 files in a folder called file1.json and file2.json

file1.json contents

```
{
   "name":"Jack",
   "age":30,
   "contactNumbers":[
      {
         "type":"Home",
         "number":"123 123-123"
      },
      {
         "type":"Office",
         "number":"321 321-321"
      }
   ],
   "spouse":null,
   "favoriteSports":[
      "Football",
      "Cricket"
   ]
}
```

file2 contents

```
{
   "name":"Roe",
   "age":34,
   "contactNumbers":[
      {
         "type":"Home",
         "number":"123 123-123"
      },
      {
         "type":"Office",
         "number":"321 321-321"
      }
   ],
   "spouse":null,
   "favoriteSports":[
      "Hockey",
      "Baseball"
   ]
}
```

Now I need to change the property `"type":"Home"` from Home to Office in both the files. Is there a way to change this without opening the file. I mean can we code it?

Expected output

```
"type":"Office"
```

Comment: What's wrong about _opening_ ?

Comment: What does it even mean to update a file without opening it?

Comment: Say there are 100 files. It not advised to open all the files and update it :) so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can programmatically change the content of JSON files without **manually** opening them. If that is what you are asking.

You do on the other hand need to:

- load them into python as objects
- modify what you need
- write the modified object back to the file

You can do something like:

```
import json

files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json']

for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for contact in data["contactNumbers"]:
        if contact["type"] == "Home":
            contact["type"] = "Office"

    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: great this is working perfectly. Really thanks. But 1 question, say the ````type```` is different across files. I mean it is not Home. It differs from file to file. But we need to update it to "Office" . Can we do this?

Comment: Just change the if contact["type"] == "Home" -> if contact["type"] != "Office".
In that case everything that's not set to "Office" will be replaced.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. But I wanted to alter few. Like there is a string "Office is far" . I want only "far" to be replaced by "near" So . I added this code ````contact["type"].replace("far", "near")````. So that the far in the string is replaced by near. But it is not working. Can you guide?